# How to write ASP.NET script to connect to SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ado.net, database-connection

I'm new to ASP.NET, as subject, how to use asp.net to connection SQL Server...

How to remote connect "localhost\Instancename", for example connect 192.168.0.2/sqlserver2

Comment: Any of a billion ways.  You need to be more specific.

Comment: Lightswitch is great for beginners: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/lightswitch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use ASP.NET to connect to a database directly. ASP is used to call backend function written in other languages like C#/VB.NET etc. which will fetch data and populate controls in the UI. e.g, You click a button. ASP will transform this click to a C# event (assuming that backend is in C#). The C# event handler will fetch data from DB and dump it into an ASP.NET table that you have on the UI (or wherever you want).

I think this will be a good place to start: http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials . It has everything you need, both in VB and in C#.

Comment: Thank, but how to remote connect "localhost\Instancename", for example connect 192.168.0.2